# Java: annotating members in single declaration

Tags: java, annotations

In Java, we can annotate members like this:

```
@Annotation
private Type member;
```

My question is, can we provide different annotations for members of the same type declared in the same statement? Something like...

```
private Type @Annotation1 member1, @Annotation2 member2;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Annotations are basically modifiers, so no. You can not intermix different annotations in a multi-declaration statement anymore than you could intermix `private`, `public`, `static`, `volatile` or any of the other Java modifiers.

If you try it out in an IDE of your choice you will be able to verify this yourself of course.

Comment: Just the answer I was looking for. "Annotations are basically modifiers", simple and to the point. +1 and accepted.